# Error while updating a Page property in Notion gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js, notion-api

Using the documentation of Notion in [here](https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-page), I am trying to update a page property on a database in my personal Notion.

The code is the following

[image]

The error is the following
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what was wrong. The "name" attribute was missing.

[image]